# What C++ [[attributes]] are implemented by cheerp?

Tags: javascript, c++, c++11, cheerp

The C++11 specification defined [`[[attributes]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) which can be used to specify/influence implementation-defined behavior. Cheerp supports this for specifying whether you're writing C++ code meant to be compiled into `[[cheerp::genericjs]]` or `[[cheerp::wasm]]` code. This results in your C++ code being compiled into the `.js` or `.wasm` output of the compiler respectively. (Right?)

My question: What attributes does Cheerp know and what do they all do?

So far, I've seen the following attributes:

```
[[cheerp::genericjs]]
[[cheerp::wasm]]
[[cheerp::asmjs]]
[[cheerp::client_layout]]
[[cheerp::static]]
[[cheerp::jsexport]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ones that are meant to be used by users are:

- `cheerp::genericjs`: compile the associated item (class/struct definition, global, or function) to JavaScript, using the object memory model
- `cheerp::wasm`: compile the associated item (class/struct definition, global, or function) to WebAssembli OR asm.js, using the linear memory model.
  `cheerp::asmjs` is an alias of `cheerp::wasm` and considered obsoleted (but kept for backward compatibility). The actual output (wasm or asm.js) depends on command line flags
- `client::jsexport`: export the associated item (function or class/struct) so that it can be used from external JavaScript code

The other attributes you mention do exist, but you should almost never use them yourself. Their meaning is this:

- `cheerp::static`: tell the compiler that the associated method of a client class is static (example: `Date.now()`). Used in the implementation of various browser apis
- `cheerp::client_layout`: tell the compiler that this class/struct has an external layout defined in external JavaScript. You never need to use this if you inherit your client classes from `client::Object` (which you should), because derived classes inherit this attribute